# Django related object in save_model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want a simple `created_by` field for an entity in Django 3.0:

Snippet from Model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, verbose_name=_('Created by'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,
                                   blank=False, related_name='created_events', editable=False)
```

*(Migrations applied.)*

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if obj is not None and obj.created_by is None:
            obj.created_by = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

On saving from the adminpage I get this error:

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /......./Events/event/add/
Event has no created_by.
```

What am I doing wrong?

What I tried to debug:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    print(obj) # Prints the __str__ output of the object correctly!
    if obj is not None and obj.created_by is None:
        user = CustomUser.objects.filter(id=request.user.id).first()
        obj.created_by = user # tried to assign a full model not just from request
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `... obj.created_by is None ...` attribute access does the harm. When you access a non-nullable FK this way it will raise the shown error. You need to test it differently, e.g.

```
if obj is not None and obj.pk is None:
    # ...
```

You can also override `save_form` instead where you have direct access to whether this is a new object:

```
def save_form(self, request, form, change):
    obj = super().save_form(request, form, change)
    if not change:
        # set user
    return obj
```

Comment: Because the properties with the values are magic properties in a dict in `__state__` and not real properties on the object?

Comment: They are in fact class attributes that implement the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) to handle lookup on instances.